# How to get text content seperated by a <BR> in using DOMDocument

Tags: php, domdocument

I have a page full of elements Im trying to parse.  I want class1 and class2 as seperate text.  However, class 2 exists inside class1.  So if I do textContent, it retrieves all the text.

Heres the structure...

```
 <div class='class1'> 
     Name <br/> <span class='class2'>Other Name</span>
  </div>
```

If I do this...

```
 $dom = new DOMDocument();
 $dom->loadHTMLFile($url);
 $finder = new DomXPath($dom);
 $classname="class2";
 $nodes = $finder->query("//*[contains(@class, '$classname')]");
 foreach($nodes as $n){
     echo $n->textContent;
 }
```

I can get the class2 elemtn just fine.
But if I do the same for class1.  I get the textContent of class1 which also includes the contents of class2.

How can I extract these seperately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, `$n` contains 5 child nodes:

1. "Name"
2. "<br/>"
3. " "
4. "<span class='class2'>Other Name</span>"
5. " "

The property `textContent` consist of the text of this node and all its descendants. 
To access the content only of the first child use:

```
echo $n->firstChild->textContent;
```

Comment: Thanks!  super simple, I feel stupid now.  How would I get the 4th element as well, so I can just use one query

Comment: Something like $node->childNodes->item(4)->textContent.  Which doesnt seem to work?

Comment: just did $node->firstChild->nextSibling->nextSibling->textContent.  Not sure if theres a bette way.  but it works, so Im happy

Comment: @KyleK You can access child nodes through `childNodes` property. `$n->childNodes[3]->textContent` will return text `Other Name`

Answer (score 0):

In plain javascript, you can filter / map to extract just the text children from the node.  Something like this:

```
var c1 = document.getElementsByClassName('class1')[0].childNodes;
var allC1Text = Array.from(c1.values())
  .filter(v => v.nodeName === '#text')
  .map(t => t.textContent)
  .join('')
  .trim();

var c2 = document.getElementsByClassName('class2')[0].childNodes;
var allC2Text = Array.from(c2.values())
  .filter(v => v.nodeName === '#text')
  .map(t => t.textContent)
  .join('')
  .trim();

console.log('Class1 Text:', allC1Text);
console.log('Class2 Text:', allC2Text);
```

Comment: That was a `php` question, not `javascript`

Answer (score 0):

Using just `DOMDocument`, I would do something like this:

```
<?php
function getElementsByClassName(DOMDocument $dom, $className, $parentNode = null){
  $node = $parentNode ? $parentNode : $dom;
  $a = array(); $all = $node->getElementsByTagName('*');
  foreach($all as $e){
    if($e->hasAttribute('class') && $e->getAttribute('class') === $className){
      $a[] = $e;
    }
  }
  return $a;
}
function getNodeValueBeforeBr($node){
  return preg_replace('/\s*<\s*br\s*\/?\s*>$/i', '', $node->nodeValue);
}
$dom = new DOMDocument; @$dom->loadHTMLFile('yourFileName.php');
$class1 = getElementsByClassName($dom, 'class1'); $results = array();
foreach($class1 as $node){
  $results[] = getNodeValueBeforeBr($node);
}
print_r($results);
?>
```